# Debugging website hosted on a remote server in VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have website (setup on IIS) in a VPS setting. Since I dont have VS installed on the VPS, I would like to connect it from my dev machine and debug the source code.

From my dev machine, I opened up VS 2008 and did File -> Open Website -> specified the http address and clicked OK. I get the error

```
"Unable to open the website 'http://xxx..'. The Web server does not have the FrontPage Server extensions installed"
```

1. Is this the correct way of debugging a website hosted remotely?
2. I have IIS 6.0 on the VPS. When I go to Add Remove Progrsms -> Add remove Windows Components -> Application Server -> IIS, I was expecting to see FrontPage Server Extensions. I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FrontPage extensions are for *developing* (or rather managing pages and adminstration of) a website, not debugging it.

You need to have a debugging host setup on the remote server and have the correct permissions and ports open between the server and development machine.

Here are a [couple](http://blogs.msdn.com/mszcool/archive/2004/10/25/247158.aspx) of [articles](http://aspnet2holes.blogspot.com/2006/11/debug-aspnet-20-running-under-iis-60.html) with deatils of how to set this up.